# In a Blazor page (Not a Blazor component) why all methods and variables are private inside @code?

Tags: blazor

Here you can see some methods and variables that are private.

I'm using a different example than the code above:
Here is the razor page index.

```
@page "/"

<Counter Title="Diego's Component" Label="Valor" CurrentValue="@counter" ValueChanged="@CounterChanged"></Counter>
<h1>Dos:</h1>

<Alert Show="@(counter>3)">
    <p>Your counter is bigger than 3</p>
</Alert>

<DismissableAlert Show="@(counter>3)">
    <p>Count too large!</p>
</DismissableAlert>



<Timer Active="@(counter>3)" Tick="@ResetCounter" TimeInSeconds="3"></Timer>

<DiegoFotos @ref="dies"></DiegoFotos>

<Timer Tick="@NextDie" TimeInSeconds="3" Active="@true"></Timer>
@code
{
    private int counter = 0;

    private void CounterChanged(int newCounter)
    {
        counter = newCounter;
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    private void ResetCounter() => this.counter = 0;

    //reference to the other component
    private DiegoFotos dies;
    public void NextDie() => dies.NextDie();
}
```

In the code above you can see a public method "NextDie"
**Thanks in advance for your clarification.**

Comment: When to use private or public methods? And What difference will make?

Comment: You will need to do some reading about [`access modifiers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)

Comment: The `@code{ ...}` part is merged into a generated C# class. All normal C# rules apply, public/private is not Blazor specific.

Comment: Regarding your edit: a Page _is_ a Component and it still doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a method or a variable as private, they are scoped to the current component, and cannot be accessed from outside.

> in Blazor why all methods and variables are private inside @code?

This is not true. You may define your methods and fields and properties as public if you wish to expose them to the external world.

As for instance, if you want to allow a parent component to pass a value to its child component, you should define a parameter public property as follows;

[Parameter]
Public string Value {get; set;}

Now, if you change the public modifier to private, this code won't work...

Note: A component is a C# class, and it has the same characteristics of a C# class in that regard, though it is a special case of a class (because of the rendering feature)

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not a Blazor component but a razor page.

Comment: If it's a razor page, why do you select the Blazor tag ? This section is about Blazor apps, not Razor Pages apps. Change the tags. Incidentally, this text from the title of your question: In a Blazor page (Not a Blazor component)...a Blazor page is always a Razor component. Anyhow, everything said above is also relevant to a Razor Pages page class as it is a C# class.